# airflow - dynamically change namespace in KubernetesPodOperator

Tags: templates, macros, airflow

I am running airflow 1.10.13 on kubernetes and trying to find a way to dynamically change the namespace I run a task on.
I tried using templates and inserting parameters from the dag_run.conf json but the template is only rendered in the 'cmds' and not in other task fields like namespace.

I would love to find a solution (using templates or any other way) to alter the namespace.

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': days_ago(1)
}

with DAG('test_ns', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='@once') as dag:
    ns = """ {{ dag_run.conf.ns }} """
    example_task= KubernetesPodOperator(namespace=ns,
                                         image='python:3.6',
                                         cmds=["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo {{ns}}"],
                                         arguments=[],
                                         task_id='example_task',
                                         name='example_task',
                                         get_logs=True,
                                         is_delete_operator_pod=True,
                                         provide_context=True
                                         )
```

Answer (score 1):

The list of [templated fields](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/03d3c7db931df34a724a3f254bf13197a9063576/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/operators/kubernetes_pod.py#L165:L173) in KubernetesPodOperator does not have `namespace`.

You can create your own operator with the same behavior that adds `namespace` to `template_fields`:

```
class MyKubernetesPodOperator(KubernetesPodOperator):
         template_fields = KubernetesPodOperator.template_fields +('namespace',)
```

Then you can use your code as:

```
with DAG('test_ns', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='@once') as dag:
    ns = """ {{ dag_run.conf.ns }} """
    example_task= MyKubernetesPodOperator(namespace=ns,...)
```

**EDIT:**
Full example with your code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.cncf.kubernetes.operators.kubernetes_pod import KubernetesPodOperator


class MyKubernetesPodOperator(KubernetesPodOperator):
    template_fields = KubernetesPodOperator.template_fields + ('namespace',)


default_args = {
    'owner': 'elad',
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 11, 1),

}

with DAG(dag_id='stackoverflow',
         default_args=default_args,
         schedule_interval=None
         ) as dag:
    ns = """ {{ dag_run.conf.ns }} """
    example_task = MyKubernetesPodOperator(namespace=ns,
                                           image='python:3.6',
                                           cmds=["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo {{ns}}"],
                                           arguments=[],
                                           task_id='example_task',
                                           name='example_task',
                                           get_logs=True,
                                           is_delete_operator_pod=True,
                                           )
```

Triggered the dag with `conf`:

```
{"ns":"mynamespace"}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks Elad, 
I got the idea but having trouble implementing it. I'm trying to find the correct syntax for creating the custom operator.
`class MyOperator(KubernetesPodOperator):
    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self,
                 *args,
                 **kwargs):
        super(MyOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        template_fields = ('namespace') + KubernetesPodOperator.template_fields
`
this version that I saw in a tutorial returns an error for the init:

__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'limit_memory

Comment: Why did you add `init`? Did you try the code in my answer? it should work just fine.

Comment: I get an invalid syntax error if I use it as is. I use version 1.10.13. 
The use of a class is my attempt to implement a new operator like I saw here:http://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/custom-operator.html

Comment: where do you import the KubernetesPodOperator from? contrib or providers?

Comment: oh it should be `('namespace',)` so it will be a tuple not a string. I'll update my answer with working example shortly.